# from sympy import Plot fail

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I am using three different ways to import Plot function. All fail.
1:

```
from sympy import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pp1,pp2,el1,el2=insline(0,0,4,0,1.5,1,1.5,1)
    print pp1.evalf(),pp2.evalf()
    p=Plot()
    p[0]=el1
    p[1]=el2
    p[2]=Segment(pp1,pp2)
    p.show()
```

Shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Erdong\workspace\Gungeo\src\gungeo.py", line 39, in <module>
p=Plot()
```

### NameError: name 'Plot' is not defined

2:

```
from sympy import Point, Ellipse, intersection, Segment,plot
import math
def
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pp1,pp2,el1,el2=insline(0,0,4,0,1.5,1,1.5,1)
    print pp1.evalf(),pp2.evalf()
    p=plot.Plot()
    p[0]=el1
    p[1]=el2
    p[2]=Segment(pp1,pp2)
    p.show()
```

Shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Erdong\workspace\Gungeo\src\gungeo.py", line 39, in <module>
p=plot.Plot()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Plot'
```

3.

```
from sympy import Plot
```

Shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Project\Build up\programming\learn\learn.py", line 7, in <module>
from sympy import Plot
ImportError: cannot import name Plot
```

Please help how to import Plot from sympy-0.7.6.

I also tried:
    from sympy.plotting.pygletplot import PygletPlot as Plot
    But got error also:
    {
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Erdong\workspace\Gungeo\src\gungeo.py", line 92, in 
    p=Plot(el1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\pygletplot__init__.py", line 139, in PygletPlot
    import plot
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\pygletplot\plot.py", line 16, in 
    from plot_axes import PlotAxes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\pygletplot\plot_axes.py", line 7, in 
    from util import strided_range, billboard_matrix
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\pygletplot\util.py", line 8, in 
    def get_model_matrix(array_type=c_float, glGetMethod=glGetFloatv):
NameError: name 'c_float' is not defined
}

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html. It should be

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
x = symbols('x')
p = plot(x)
```

Comment: I want to plot a ellipse which has sympy format such as $Ellipse(Point(0,0),2.3)$. In reference, I didn't see"plot" could use for ellipse drawing. Only "Plot" could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the old Plot that uses pyglet:

```
from sympy.plotting.pygletplot import PygletPlot as Plot
```

Comment: Got error:    NameError: name 'c_float' is not defined